# Ubuntu interface issue: Black screen terminal after Python reinstallation

Tags: ubuntu, desktop-environment

I can't access my Ubuntu interface as I only see the terminal. This happened after I accidentally deleted my default Python. I then reinstalled it, but upon starting my PC again, it just brought up a black screen terminal. I am new to Linux, so I don't know much, but this problem has been bothering me. Please help, and thanks.

Comment: I assume that what you mean by "black screen terminal" is that the graphical login screen does not appear, and you are instead presented with a `login:` prompt in a text console, right?